# How do i append a comma to every line except the last in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the code below that produces the output

**Output**

```
abc : 1
def : 2
ghi : 3
```

**Code**

```
var fso, f1, ts, s;
var ForReading = 1;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
// Read the contents of the file.
Session.Output("Reading file");
ts = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\temp\\text.txt", ForReading);
s = ts.ReadAll();
u = s.split('\r\n');
for(i = 0; i < u.length; i++){
m = u[i].split(",");
var z = m[0] + " : " + (m[0] = m[1]);
}
ts.Close();
```

I need the output as follows;

```
    abc : 1,
    def : 2,
    ghi : 3
```

Comment: Put all parts into an array, and call `.join(",\n")` or something

Comment: @Ian - Do you have an example? Am new to arrays, joins & splits

Comment: Advice: (a) `var` your local variables. (b) Use sensible variable names. (c) `m[0]=m[1]` did you perhaps mean `==`?

Comment: @Phrogz - Thanks Phrogz. I am testing portion of existing code and hence haven't bothered doing some housekeeping yet.

Comment: @Phrogz - No. I meant `m[0] = m[1]`. If you try `m[0] == m[1]`, it returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a comma to all but the last iteration of the `for` loop.

```
var fso, f1, ts, s;
var ForReading = 1;
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
// Read the contents of the file.
Session.Output("Reading file");
ts = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\\temp\\text.txt", ForReading);
s = ts.ReadAll();
u = s.split('\r\n');
for(i = 0; i < u.length; i++){
    m = u[i].split(",");
    var z = m[0] + " : " + (m[0] = m[1]);
    if(i != u.length - 1){ //<---
        z = z + ",";
    }
    console.log(z + "\n"); //something like this...
}
ts.Close();
```

Answer (score 3):

You want [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var commaDelimited = lines.join(",\n");
```

This takes an array, calls `toString()` on each entry if necessary, and joins them with the string you supply.

In your case:

```
var lines = s.split('\r\n');
var result = [];
for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++){
  var parts = lines[i].split(",");
  result.push( parts[0] + " : " + parts[1] );
}
var output = result.join(",\n");
```

Alternatively, using [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a more *functional* style of programming:

```
var output = s.split('\r\n').map(function(line){
  return line.split(",").join(" : ");
}).join(",\n");
```

Comment: I thought it may be join but am unsure how to use it in my example.

Comment: That doesn't quite work. The output repeats itself and it isn't correct e.g. `abc,1: def, 2`